# UI controls not showing on fragment- android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to android. Using fragment for the 1st time. I have button, imagebutton, edittext, textview in fragment.xml(named fragment_plus_one.xml). I created mainActivity. I have 4 buttons in mainActivity. On clicking button3, a new fragment(as mentioned earlier) opens. But those uI controls are not showing on fragment. For textview, i have used tv.setText("yourText");Still text is not showing. How to show them.
[before clicking button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXgdZ.jpg)

[after clicking button3; no ui shown, only view is inflated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD41q.jpg)
activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="fill_vertical" android:layout_margin="0dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button4"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >

    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn3, btn4;
    PlusOneFragment myf;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
        btn3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                myf = new PlusOneFragment();
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.frameLayout, myf);
                transaction.commit();

            }
        });

        btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                myf.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);    
            }
        });
    }
}
```

fragment_plus_one.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="fill_vertical" android:layout_margin="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical" android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/seat_serial_prefix"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-"
            android:lines="1"
            android:hint="Seat Serial Prefix">
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/seat_serial_start_number"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:lines="1"
            android:hint="Seat Serial Start Number">
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/seat_serial_end_number"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:lines="1"
            android:hint="Seat Serial End Number">
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Generate"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Generate" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="fill_horizontal" android:layout_margin="0dp">

        <FrameLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical" android:layout_margin="10dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonGenerateBulk"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Generate Qr Code"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tv_question"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_question"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:src="@drawable/qr_code"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="Generate" >
            </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="Bulk" >
        </TextView>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="fill_vertical" android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonGenerateSingle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Generate Qr Code"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tv_question"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_question"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:src="@drawable/qr_code"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="Generate" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="Single" >
        </TextView>
    </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

PlusOneFragment.java:

```
public class PlusOneFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public PlusOneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment PlusOneFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static PlusOneFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        PlusOneFragment fragment = new PlusOneFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plus_one, container, false);
        TextView tv= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.seat_serial_prefix);
        tv.setText("yourText");
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is your "@+id/frameLayout" width set to 0dp? It should be set to wrap content or fill parent.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `0dp` value of `FrameLayout` in `activity_main` to `wrap_content`, then everything will work as it should!